# Can a labor strike, and closure of supermarkets, restrict the EU Freedom to Provide Services?

Tags: european-union

Here are the facts of a hypothetical case.

> Company is a family company producing cheese in Italy. Since its gorgonzola cheese is quite successful in the domestic market, it decides to start exporting it to other Member States  on  the eve of a holiday, like Easter, that can bolster marketing and sales.

> In March, C starts exporting to France, distributing gorgonzola through big supermarkets. On 14 March, it learns that the Fédération des Epiciers (grocers' federation) was authorized to go on a strike throughout the week before Easter,  and that all supermarkets would be closed during that week. Owing to this strike, less than 2% of C's merchandise was sold. C sought reparation from the French
> administrative authorities who rejected C's claims.

> C now considers suing to
> recover its losses in France. Can EU law assist?

I noted what my law teacher said — this closing of shops doesn't restrict the EU [Freedom to Provide Services](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freedom_of_Establishment_and_Freedom_to_Provide_Services_in_the_European_Union). But she didn't explain. Why not?

Comment: If your train is late, is that against your freedom of movement?

Comment: If no one wants to hire a particular EU citizen as an employee in France, is their right to work anywhere in the Union infringed?

Comment: @gnasher729 No, but can you please elaborate? Unquestionably, the facts of this case  are more complicated.

Comment: @xngtng No, but can you please elaborate? Unquestionably, the facts of this case  are more complicated.